# Locating libcrypto.so.4 for Cisco IOU use in GNS3

Tags: command-line

**Edit**: As per the [response](https://www.gns3.com/qa/l2-iou-setup-missing-dependencie) I received over at the GNS3 forums, looks like the IOU binary is 32-bit and therefore require 32-bit libraries.

---

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask but I hope someone here has some insight. I'm working on getting L2 IOU images up and running  in GNS3 and I'm stuck at an issue. This is on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The images won't run because it says it's missing dependencies, specifically libcrypto.so.4.

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chcHuF3nEoQ) that was supposed to be remedy however it wasn't based on Ubuntu. Following that, I issued the following commands to try and fix it.

> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** find / -name '*libcrypto*' 2> /dev/null
>
> /home/tinyrick/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /lib/libcrypto.so.4
>
> [sudo] password for tinyrick:
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.4
>
> [sudo] password for tinyrick:
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$**

The video had used the /usr/ base directory so I tried that after leaving it out failed me.

In contiunation, I have removed both symbolic links to try and tried to use another suggested command to find the dependency. The following is the output of such....

> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** sudo rm /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.4
>   [sudo] password for tinyrick:
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** sudo rm
>   /lib/libcrypto.so.4
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$** whereis libcrypto.so.4
>
> libcrypto.so:
>
> **tinyrick@tinyrick-PC:~$**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the 32bit version of the library, if you have a 64bit system this wont be downloaded.

To download the 32bit version go to https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/diag/missinglibssl

Then you can create a symbolic link using:

```
find / -name '*libcrypto*' 2> /dev/null
```

Look for something like:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Then create the link:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.4
```

Credit to the YouTube video that helped finding the solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chcHuF3nEoQ